# How to query access table in a mssql server view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I'd like to create a view to query an access table. I know that each view must contain a "SELECT" clause so I guess that I must use a stored procedure to be called within a view using OPENQUERY. Do you think it's doable in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done with  [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT        *
FROM            OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'e:\test.mdb'; 'admin'; '', table1)   AS a

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[openrowset_to_access_file_v]
```

[image: Screenshot]

The **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0** provider is used with 32-bit SQL Server for Access/Excel 2003 files.

The **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** provider is used with 64-bit SQL Server for any Access/Excel files or 32-bit SQL Server for Access/Excel 2007 files.

[image: Screenshot]